# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar 'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo de datos int

Tags: c#, combobox

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Al seleccionar en un combobox el código de usuario quiero que en otro combobox me diga el nombre de ese usuario, al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar 'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo de datos int.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-B1MVQBF ; database=biblioteca ; integrated security = true");
    conexion.Open();
                
    string consulta = "select nombre_usuario from usuarios where codigo_usuario='"+comboBox3.Text+"'";
    SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(consulta,conexion);
    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
    DataTable d = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(d);
    txtnom.Text = comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();
    
    cmbnom.DataSource = d;
    cmbnom.DisplayMember = "nombre_usuario";
    cmbnom.ValueMember = "nombre_usuario"; 
}
```

En la BBDD el código de usuario lo tengo como `int`.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Un saludo.

Comment: En que linea te da el error? en sqlDataAdapter? o en txtnom. text?

Comment: comboBox3.Text <-- no es selectedvalue? o selectedtext???? dependiendo de entorno grafico uses... y tu problema no tiene nada que ver con visual studio!!!!!